# Associative array in bash not storing values inside loop

Tags: bash, associative-array, bash4

This is my `$a` output:

```
[root@node1 ~]# echo "${a}"
/dev/vdc1 /gfs1
/dev/vdd1 /elastic
mfsmount /usr/local/flytxt
```

I gotta store these in an associative array `fsmounts` with first column as keys and second col as value.
This is my code for that:

```
declare -A fsmounts
echo "$a" | while read i ; do key=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $1}'); value=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $2}');fsmounts[$key]=$value;  done;
```

But when I try to print outside the loop with

```
[root@node1 ~]# echo ${fsmounts[/dev/vdb1]}
```

Blank is the output. I think the associative array fsmounts is not actually storing values. Please help me.

But I can actually able to echo `fsmounts[$key]` inside the loop. See this:

```
echo "$a" | while read i ; do key=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $1}'); value=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $2}');fsmounts[$key]=$value; echo ${fsmounts[$key]};  done;
/gfs1
/elastic
/usr/local/flytxt
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The imminent problem associated with your logic is [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

You don't need `awk` or any third party tool at all for this. Just run it over a loop with a `read` and feed the string via standard input over the loop

```
declare -A fsmounts

while read -r key value; do
    fsmounts["$key"]="$value"
done <<<"$a"
```

now loop over the array with key and values

```
for key in "${!fsmounts[@]}"; do
    printf 'key=%s value=%s\n' "$key" "${fsmounts[$key]}"
done
```

More on how to use associative arrays - [How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)